# Magento2 admin menu panel doesn't work

Tags: admin, magento2, adminhtml

magento2 dashboard:

All admin menu links don't work and have a strange icon. Why it's not working? Does anyone have any idea?

[image]

I can't do anything.

Answer (score 26):

Below solution worked for me
just try it.
go to **app/etc/di.xml**

find the line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and Replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

There is no need to remove any file in any directory.

Comment: My Pleasure!!..Enjoy coding Dhaval...

Comment: @PriyaPonnusamy, could you explain how and why does this solution work ? In 2.1.x - the code already has this line
`<argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            </argument>`

Comment: You need to have a capital in Copy or it doesn't work. Please update your answer.

Comment: @Vikram have you fixed the issue? Sorry about the delay in my response

Comment: @PriyaPonnusamy: I am not sure how and why does this solution work  ?

Comment: @Vikram are you facing this issue? if so which version you're using?

Comment: Thanks its worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I hope this will help you

> Goto Magento 2 root directory -> pub -> **static** and remove **static** folder and remove **var/cache**, **var/composer_home**, **var/generation**, **var/page_cache**, **var/view_preprocessed**

Then run,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Caution while removing pub/static contents do not remove .htaccess file otherwise css and javasrcipt will not render and page will load with text only.

Answer (score 3):

Disable JS merge from admin:

```
Go to System->Configuration->Developer
```

or if Admin menu not working then 
Goto database inside table **core_config_data** change key **dev/js/merge_files** from 1 to 0

Answer (score 3):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path

```
“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”
```

and replace to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/stati`c except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: Note that this only works in developer mode.

Answer (score 2):

try to run this

```
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

This stumped me momentarily earlier, make sure your `magento_root/` directory is accessible through your web server and not just the `magento_root/pub/` directory - you can use aliases or change your web root.

Comment: Please can you provide further insight? Allowing access to the entire magento root is less secure, so I'd rather keep the pub folder symlinked. I've already added aliases in my apache2.conf file for the /setup and /upgrade directories, so where would I need it to point to in order to resolve this error.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood Sorry, this was only relevant to me on Apache and we have since switched to Nginx (which I'd recommend by the way, it works very well in our case).

Comment: Ok thanks! I did just read about 10 minutes ago that people are having much more success with nginx. Could I also ask how you've set up the rest of your stack, or at least whether you use varnish and which version? I'm having trouble running varnish 5 with magento on ubuntu 18.04 but not sure if its bionic or I just need to downgrade to varnish 4.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood Stack is straightforward, Ubuntu (16.04) -> Varnish (4.1) ->Nginx (1.10) -> PHP-FPM (7.2). We also utilise Redis to share sessions and cache between our frontend servers. We've just stuck with Varnish 4.1 because it works and is rock solid but that means I haven't looked at any upgrade yet so I can't comment on possible problems with 5.x...

Comment: Ah OK thanks. I'll give it a go on 4. Getting all kinds of problems with ports

Answer (score 2):

Goto Magento 2 root directory -> pub -> static and remove static folder and remove var/cache, var/composer_home, var/generation, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed

Then run,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and them

app/etc/di.xml

Go to the line number 574 line:

Older line:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

Replace it with (New line)

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy
```

0
down vote

I just did the following:

```
cd magento2 folder
run shell command
```

My System:

```
magento 2.0.2
xampp 7.0.3
windows 7
```

Justin@GATEWAY f:\xampp\htdocs\mag2

```
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Note that editing the Symlink entry in `di.xml` only affects websites in Developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

I applied all of the above fixes but there's one thing that is left unmentioned...

When I went to edit I had to change permissions on the folder to be able to save the changes. After I saved the edit to `di.xml`, I changed the permissions back to 444, Deleted all cache files, and reloaded. It didn't work.

After a few tries, I left the write permission on the folder, deleted cache, and only then did the fix take place.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps and it should for you

Step 1. Deleted the static folder using rm -R static/*

Step 2. Cleared cache php bin/magento cache:clean & php bin/magento cache:flush

Step 3. Reran compile php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Step 4. Generated static content php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Step 5. Changed permissions to 777 for pub/static folder chmod 777 -R . /static

Followed those steps and my admin backend loaded fine.

Answer (score 1):

it worked fine for me Magento 2.3.4

1. put magento in maintenance mode from the command console

   bin/magento maintenance:enable
2. delete everything from pub/static

> do not delete .htaccess file

3. now use the command line

   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU -f

> give it 5 minutes to complete

en_AU is Australian english so you make sure you use your own preffered language

4. once its done now clean and flush cache.

   bin/magento cache:clean

   bin/magento cache:flush
5. Disable maintenance mode

   bin/magento maintenance:disable

Answer (score 0):

Hi I having solution of the above problem.

open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

> ```
> $ cd /var/www/html/MagentoFolder
>
> $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```

Comment: it is giving this error in magento2.0:
**PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 364**

Answer (score 0):

1. First delete everything from `pub/static` folder except the `.htaccess` file
2. Secondly find

   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

in `app/etc/di.xml` file and replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, just solved by **going to**:
app/etc/di.xml

**Replacing**:
*Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink* 
**for**:

*Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy*

Refresh your browser and bingo!!

Answer (score 0):

**edit di.xml**

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

**change to**

```
<arguments>
            <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            </argument>
```

after that deploy and reindex, the problem will be solved admin panel will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of css and js are not rendering properly.

You should use CLI for compiling magento.

Here is a screenshot of my cmd usage. Please change your magento folder location as your magento folder structure.
[image]

It will take some to complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you use different languages on admin and frontend, For example, Admin en_US and front end nl_NL put them both in the same language.

You can change admin language from the admin panel by clicking on admin in the right upper corner and then Account Setting (your account name)

After this run :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

or

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL
```

or whatever your language is (or installed language pack)

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy your_LANGUAGE
```

edit:

It is possible to run the above command for multiple languages.
Example:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_GB en_US

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

execute the above commands i hope its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more row to `core_config_data` table path = `dev/static/sign` set value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that I was executing `setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` in order to match my website's locale, however I had not changed the default language of the admin user to en_GB, so the admin page was trying to locate resources from the en_US directory which, of course, was never created.

One solution would be to run `setup:static-content:deploy en_US`, generating the missing files. However, this would involve generating static content, logging in to the admin panel, changing the default language of the admin user, then deleting static content and re-generating.

In order to utilise the existing static content, I navigated to the `admin_user` table in my Magento database and located the row corresponding to the admin user in question, then changed the value of `interface_locale` to `en_GB`.

Minified JS and CSS work perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I update 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

not this below salutation not working on 2.2.7

find the line

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and Replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

There is no need to remove any file in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Open Command Prompt
- Go to Path C:\xampp\htdocs\magento
- Write a command ---

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

- Now, Run the admin panel.

Hopefully, It might be helpful.

Thanks!

Sid

Answer (score 0):

Open **\app\etc\di.xml** in Line No. 715

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
 Replace To 
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

It Will Be definitely Work

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by **Magento's cache** and **Web Browser's cache**.

Follow the steps below to resolve it:

1. Make sure there's a `.htaccess` file inside /pub/static folder.
2. Set permission of `/pub/static` folder to writable permission (0755).
3. Deploy your view: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
4. Press `Ctrl + F5` when viewing the admin page to refresh your Web Browser's cache **(important)**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Delete all folders under pub/static | Except for .htaccess
Delete var/cache
Delete var/composer_home
Delete var/generation
Delete var/page_cache
Delete var/view_preprocessed
```

Run:

```
$ bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score -2):

set right folder/file permissions

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; &&  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; && chmod 777 ./app/etc  && chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml


chown -R :<web server group> .
```

Comment: Downvoted because of 777