# Admin menus not working in magento 2.0.4

Tags: magento-2.0.4

After successful installation of magento 2.0.4 when I login in admin panel and clicking on left menus sales,products & other it is again redirecting me on dashboard. Any one can suggest something so that the other menus functionality can work in my local environment?

Comment: See here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92660/magento2-admin-menu-panel-doesnt-work