# Such big error existing in magento 2, why it is not fixed more than 2 years?

Tags: magento2

I installed magento CE 2.1.5. Then I found default logo cannot load. Even worse, left side link in admin panel cannot work at not. Then I found the solution in here(https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124967/52478)

This solution fix my above two problems. I thin many people had the same problem like me. Why magento developers do not fix this such issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running on Windows?  Windows is the only OS that doesn't handle symlinks appropriately.  All other *nix based OSes work.

I'm not sure if this was ever reported as an issue to Magento, so they may never have even put this on their list of things to address.  This is also only affecting a minority of developers as most people run their development boxes as a VM running Linux.  If you're still having issues, I would tell you to try the Magento DevBox.  If the issue persists, then report it to Magento through GitHub.