# Magento2 admin panel sidebar menu doesn't work

Tags: magento2, admin

I just install magento and open my admin panel. But non of sidebar menu are working. I got [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124967) and change following code from

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy
```

But noting works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to root of your magento 2 installation and run below commands step by step.
Delete all folders under pub/static but keep .htaccess file.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

once changed

```
Delete all folders under pub/static
Delete var/cache
Delete var/composer_home
Delete var/generation
Delete var/page_cache
Delete var/view_preprocessed
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Ensure that permissions for files folders are setup properly:
>   (More information can be found at http://devdocs.magento.com/)

```
cd $MAGENTO_HOME/ 

/* Setup File Owner Groups */
chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento

/* Setup Permission for files to 644 */
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        

/* Setup Permission for directories to 755 */
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        

/* Setup Permission for var folder to 777 */
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                

/* Setup Permission for Media Content to 777 */
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

/* Setup Permissions for Config Files and Folders */
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

> Clear temp/cached files:

```
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/static/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/generated/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/composer_home/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/generation/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/di/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/tmp/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/cache/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/page_cache/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/var/session/*
```

> Setup your local instance to run on `Developer` mode:

```
$MAGENTO_HOME/bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

> (Optional) Clear logs files

**Note: This will make it easier for you locate and identify the log file with the stack trace, if/when there is an application error per se.**

```
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/log/*
rm -rfv $MAGENTO_HOME/pub/report/*
```

> Clear your browser(s) cache.

Once the above-mentioned steps are completed, attempt to access your Admin console again.

If the issue still persists, open your Browser's Console (e.g: On FireFox: Right Click -> Inspect Element -> Console Tab) and check if there are any errors listed on there.
(If yes - please send me a screenshot of the error)

Answer (score 0):

Go to root of your magento 2 installation and follow below step.
 Delete all folders under pub/static but keep .htaccess file,and run below commands

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> chmod -R 777 var pub

Before doing above go to **app/etc/di.xml**

find the line

**Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink** 
and Replace it with

**Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy**