# Magento2 admin panel menu not working

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I have Installed Magento2  frontend is working fine but there is haviing some issue with admin panel in the backend.
Menus not working
I had already tries
[This Modification](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92660/magento2-admin-menu-panel-doesnt-work) but still it didn't work

[image]

Comment: Open console to see errors or check exception.log and debug.log for more info

Comment: [2022-08-03 07:00:00] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /var/www/html/pitstop/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:176)"}

Comment: [2022-08-03 07:02:33] main.ERROR: Command "info:adminurl" is not defined.